# How to pass parameter as date by subtracting days to a SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, date, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes two parameters, `@FromDate` and `@ToDate`. But the `@fromDate` should be `GetDate()-90`. How can I pass the parameter value?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spMyProcedure 
    @FromDate DATE,
    @ToDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    // SQL statements
END
```

I want to execute it like this:

```
EXEC spMyProcedure   @FromDate = GETDATE() - 60, @ToDate = GETDATE()
```

But it throws an error.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error?? Remember: we **cannot** read your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **tell us!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do an alter/math/etc on a value passing to a stored procedure. You can declare a date above the stored procedure and then pass that value like this:

```
DECLARE @PassDate AS DATETIME
SET @PassDate = GETDATE() - 60

EXEC spMyProcedure @FromDate = @PassDate, @ToDate = GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are working with SQL Server if so, then use `dateadd()` function inside the stored procedure

```
set @FromDate  = dateadd(day, -90, getdate())
```